# VisualSVN: Can access repo via server name but not URL, "path not found"

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN 4.3.1. Community License using self-signed certificate for signalr.domain.net (not real url).

I can update/commit/browse the repositories using the server name, ie https://signalr/CADE but I can't reach it by it's url, https://signalr.domain.net/CADE... even from within the server itself.  I've checked the following:

- Right click on repository shows proper url (https://signalr.domain.net/CADE)
- Domain pings to proper IP
- Firewall is turned off
- I can use browser on server, shows when using server name but not url
- I can use Tortoise repo-browser, shows when using server name but not url
- Server Manager shows HTTP service running, VDFS disabled,

Answer (score 0):

1. You should specify the **exact wording of the error** you receive. The problem is unclear now.
2. You need to run the `nslookup signalr` and `nslookup signalr.domain.net` commands to determine whether the name correctly points to the server computer's IP address.
3. Do not turn off the firewall. You need to make sure that your firewall allows incoming connections on port 443 (if that's the port selected in VisualSVN Server Properties). Note that VisualSVN Server by default adds a Windows Firewall rule `VisualSVN Server (TCP-In)`.

Comment: Exact Wording is: Unable to connect to a repository at https://signalr.domain.net 'CADE' path not found.  Server is used for many more things so there is no doubt of the DNS pointing to the correct IP  Firewall was temporarily turned off to verify it wasn't the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be IIS.  I didn't create a web on this server but IIS was running and taking ports 80 and 443.  I changed the VisualSVN to use https://signalr.domain.net:8443 and everything works fine now.